# Why do i have access to internal methods outside of the namespace?

Tags: c#, abstraction, access-modifiers

I am trying to understand access modifiers but i am a bit confused with how to use `internal`.

I have class in a namespace that looks like this:

```
namespace Grids
{
    public abstract class Grid
    {
        internal abstract Vector2Int ToGrid(float worldX, float worldY);
        internal Vector2Int ToGrid(Vector3 worldPoint) => ToGrid(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.z);
        internal Vector2Int ToGrid(Vector2 worldPoint) => ToGrid(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y);
    }
}
```

This is then implemented in an inherited class like so:

```
namespace Grids
{
    public class RectGrid : Grid
    {
        public int Width;
        public int Height;
        public Grid(int w, int h)
        {
             Width = w;
             Height = h;
        }
        internal override Vector2Int ToGrid(float worldX, float worldY)
        {
            int col = Mathf.FloorToInt(worldX / Width);
            int row = Mathf.FloorToInt(worldY / Height);
            return new Vector2Int(col, row);
        }
    }
}
```

So i now make a class to use this Grid thats not part of the namespace:

```
using Grids;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RectGrid _rectGrid;
    
    void Awake() {
        _rectGrid = new RectGrid(1,1);   
        _rectGrid.ToGrid(Vector3.zero); // why do i have access to this function         
    }
}
```

Yet for some reason i have access to the functions which are suppose to be internal:

Why is this ? I don't want to expose this function i want it only accessible to my `Map` class which shares the same `Grids` namespace and will control what i do expose. Yet my `MapGenerator` class has access without even being part of the namespace?

Have i misunderstood how internal works here?

Comment: Internal types or members are accessible ***only*** within files in the same ***assembly***

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)? Notice the word "assembly", not "namespace".

Comment: Ah wasn't sure what that meant. Damn thats annoying then - difficult to design a way to hide these functions but still give access to a specific class.

Comment: `difficult to design a way to hide these functions but still give access to a specific class.` protected perhaps?

Comment: How do i expose protected to the `Map` class which does not inherit it but has a reference of `Grid` ?

Basically i want `Map` to control what methods are exposed from the `Grid` class which the `MapGenerator` will call upon to generate the map.

Comment: Are inner classes an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation [internal (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)

> Internal types or members are accessible ***only*** within files in
> the same ***assembly***

As per your comment

> [It's] difficult to design a way to hide these functions but still give
> access to a specific class.

The standard *access modifiers* are fairly limited, you would need put the calling code in the same *assembly* to use `internal`. Additionally there is no way to grant an access list for calling classes unless you do this at runtime.

However, you could use an [Explicit Interface Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). This will not completely limit access, but it will make it so you need to explicitly ask for it, and hides it any other time.

```
public interface IGrid
{
    Vector2Int ToGrid(...);
}

public abstract class Grid : IGrid
{
   Vector2Int IGrid.ToGrid(...) {}
}
```

**Usage**

```
var rectGrid = new RectGrid();
((IGrid)rectGrid).ToGrid(); // you need to explicitly cast to the interface
```

Comment: Ah i see, surprised C# has never implemented more ways to control the access of functions such as having a controller to define what should be public or protected of another class. Would be quite useful to make usage of libraries a bit less cluttered.